# WP_query for posts with same post type AND same post category

Tags: wp-query, loop

I'm trying to display 'related articles', I do this now like this:

```
                <?php
                    $exclude = get_the_ID();

                    $args = array(
                        'post_type' => 'article', 
                        'posts_per_page' => 3,
                    );
                    $your_query = new WP_Query( $args );

                    echo '<ul>';
                    while( $your_query->have_posts() ) : $your_query->the_post();
                        if( $exclude != get_the_ID() ) {
                            echo '<li><a href="' . get_permalink() . '">' .
                                get_the_title() . '</a></li>';
                        }
                    endwhile;
                    echo '</ul>';
                ?>
```

This works great.. But the custom post type 'articles' actually also has categories. So I'd like to only display links from within the same category.

This is where I'm stuck, I tried giving my args array a new line:

```
$category = get_the_category();

                    $args = array(
                        'post_type' => 'article', 
                        'posts_per_page' => 3,
                        'cat'=> $category 
                    );
```

But this doesn't do the trick.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using default `category` for custom post type. You can instead use a taxonomy query to get filtered result based upon your custom taxonomy terms.

Try this -

```
$cat_ids = array();

$postID = get_the_ID();

$categories = get_the_terms($postID, 'custom_taxonomy_name'); //this will give all the terms

foreach($categories as $cat) {
    $cat_ids[] = $cat->term_id; //you may put some condition and consider only some specific terms as per your requirement
}

$args = array(
                    'post_type' => 'article', 
                    'posts_per_page' => 3,
                    'tax_query' => array(array( 
                    'taxonomy' => 'custom_taxonomy_name',
                    'field' => 'id',
                    'terms' => $cat_ids //ids of specified terms
                    )
                  )
               );
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I tried to add your code and I'm getting no results though (yet there are 2 articles in the same category) do you see anything wrong here?: http://pastebin.com/sShZw2Nq

Comment: Nevermind found what was wrong, thank you so much!